# While loop stop in the middle and not return anything?

Tags: c#, while-loop

this is my C# program for printing a series of prime numbers up to N numbers, depend on the input.

ex: if 100 inputted, it will print 100 prime numbers
ex: if 3 inputted, it will print 2, 3, 5

when I inputted 2, the program worked fine, it would print 2 and 3 but when I inputted 3 it just freeze and not doing anything after printed 3, no return log or error log, every line of code after that also won't work.

```
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("input: ");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int isPrimeFlag = 1;
            int count = 1;
            int number = 2;
            while (count <= n)
            {
                for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
                {
                    if (number % i == 0)
                    {
                        isPrimeFlag = 0;
                    }
                }

                if (isPrimeFlag == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("number: " +number);
                    Console.WriteLine("count: " +count);
                    count++;
                }

                number++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("n: " +n);
            Console.WriteLine("count: " +count);
```

as long as the input is lower than 3, the program run as normal.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You only increment `count` if you found a prime - please learn how to use the debugger to step through your code.

Comment: Another solution you could try is it to keep track of all the primes you've found so far and then you only need to check the modulo against them instead of incrementing from 2.

Comment: IsPrimeFlag is deciding on truth, it should be a Boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

isPrimeFlag variable is not being reset to 1 at the beginning of each iteration in the while loop. So,once isPrimeFlag is set to 0, it stays 0, causing the loop to run indefinitely without incrementing the count variable.

To fix the issue, try reset the isPrimeFlag variable to 1 at the beginning of each iteration in the while loop

Try this dude

```
int n;
Console.WriteLine("input: ");
n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int isPrimeFlag;
int count = 1;
int number = 2;
while (count <= n)
{
    isPrimeFlag = 1; // Reset the flag at the beginning of each iteration
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            isPrimeFlag = 0;
            break; // You can break the loop early if a factor is found
        }
    }

    if (isPrimeFlag == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("number: " + number);
        Console.WriteLine("count: " + count);
        count++;
    }

    number++;
}

Console.WriteLine("n: " + n);
Console.WriteLine("count: " + count);
```